# Waiting (TTFB) too high and font delay involved?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've some trouble in the optimization of my pages. I've turned off cache and inspect the performance in google developer tool in chrome. Every page load takes about 17 seconds to start rendering the page, then 3-4 seconds to load all the rest, and about 10-15 seconds to apply the custom font loaded. I've take a look inside the network panel and waterfall:
[image]
[image]

So the problem is the font used in the page. Here how the @font-face look inside the CSS external file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'belwehbold';
src: url('../fonts/Belwe-ExtraBold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Belwe-ExtraBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/Belwe-ExtraBold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/Belwe-ExtraBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/Belwe-ExtraBold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
main {
font-family: 'Helvetica';
font-size: 20px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 1230px;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
background: transparent;
}
.fonts-loaded main {
  font-family: 'belwehbold';
}
```

Inside every page I use fontFaceObserver to "delay" the problem in this way:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="preload" as="style" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">

<script src="js/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
<script>
var font = new FontFaceObserver('belwehbold');

font.load().then(function () {
  console.log('Font is available');}, function () {
      console.log('Font is not available');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

After a new inspect the result is the same, but 'Font is not available', as stated by the console. The font is about 25kb and in .htaccess all the file is compressed this way:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# Komprimiere HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML und fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/text font/opentype font/truetype font/eot


  # Browser bugs entfernen (nur fÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¼r wirklich alte Browser)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Not the main problem but why are you using font formats that literally don't exist anymore? `eot` was already obsolete but got killed when MS discontinued all IE except IE11 in January 2016 (two years ago!). And any browser that properly supports ttf also supports WOFF, and supports that better (because woff doesn't need _all_ the data ttf/otf does) so just load woff2 with woff fallback and you're done.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good point, fixed it. I think I've found the guilty for this problem, if confirmed I will answer this question tomorrow, just to help someone in the same condition.

Comment: @Flavio, what was the reason and how did you fix it?

Comment: It’s a kind of “redirect” from the server side. You have to choose the main url, if it’s registered without www. the server will always try to use a road and if it’s “full” the server will redirect the other one. Don’t know why but it’s a problem i can see only on a font. If you don’t use multiple redirect on the server side you will solve the problem.